# how to use C++ to control the display and shutdown of the TabTip keyboard

Tags: c++, windows

1,Can anyone tell me the difference between tabtip and osk keyboard?
2,I want to know how to use C++ to control the display and shutdown of the TabTip keyboard?

I tried to close the tabtip.exe by turning off the osk system keyboard but it didn't work.

First of all, I have tried to use the FindWindow function to return a valid window handle to find the window that needs to be closed/minimized. And then display the TabTip window by calling SendMessage.

```
if (HWND hwnd = FindWindow(L"IPTip_Main_Window", 0))
{
    SendMessage(hwnd, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SW_SHOW, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the code below, it can kill the process of TabTip, and then open it, which can also fulfill your needs.

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <TlHelp32.h>
#include <tchar.h>
BOOL GetPidByProcessName(TCHAR *pProcess, DWORD *dwPid)
{
    HANDLE hSnapshot;
    PROCESSENTRY32 lppe;
    hSnapshot = ::CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, NULL);

    if (hSnapshot == NULL)
        return FALSE;
    lppe.dwSize = sizeof(lppe);
    if (!::Process32First(hSnapshot, &lppe))
        return FALSE;
    do
    {
        if (_tcscmp(lppe.szExeFile, pProcess) == 0)
        {
            *dwPid = lppe.th32ProcessID;
        }
    } while (::Process32Next(hSnapshot, &lppe));

    return TRUE;
}
BOOL KillProcess(DWORD ProcessId)
{
    HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_TERMINATE, FALSE, ProcessId);
    if (hProcess == NULL)
        return FALSE;
    if (!TerminateProcess(hProcess, 0))
        return FALSE;
    return TRUE;
}
int main()
{
    HWND TabTip = FindWindow(L"IPTip_Main_Window", 0);
    if (!TabTip)
    {
        ShellExecute(NULL, L"open", L"C:\\Program Files\\Common Files\\microsoft shared\\ink\\TabTip.exe", NULL, NULL, SW_SHOW);
    }
    else
    {
        TCHAR a[256] = _T("TabTip.exe");
        DWORD b = 0;
        GetPidByProcessName(a, &b);
        KillProcess(b);
        ShellExecute(NULL, L"open", L"C:\\Program Files\\Common Files\\microsoft shared\\ink\\TabTip.exe", NULL, NULL, SW_SHOW);
    }


}
```

Best Regards,

Suarez Zhou

Comment: Thanks Suarez for your time and support.